# Which API to use for Here.com to see a truck route drawn on a map?

Tags: here-api

It seems like I need to use the Routing API. I want to be able to get results drawn on a map, similar to what Google Maps provides. From the Here.com documentation, I can't tell if that's a possibility.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, different transport modes in Routing API allow the creation of routes that consider rules and restrictions related to specific transport types: cars, trucks, scooters, and so on.

With a specific transport mode enabled, the various Routing services use road network segments allowed for use by vehicles of the selected type while taking into account the restrictions that might be applicable. More can be found [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/transport-modes.html)

Comment: I appreciate that! How can I actually get those onto a map, though? Do I need to use the flexible polylines with a different API or JavaScript integration?

Comment: There's this [example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/truck-routing-road-restrictions) which might help you to get the truck routes and road restrictions on the map.